# Windows 7 Cable Connection Rehabilitation

Tags: windows-7, connection, cable

I recently switched the operating system of my laptop from Windows XP to Windows 7.

My web-connection is such that I need to identify everytime before connecting. Since there is no automatic identification request, while using Windows XP I was used to de-abilitate and rehabilitate the cable connection after every switching on.

I successfully installed the web-connection on Windows 7, and later on I switched the computer off and on (simply because I had to sleep!). After restarting the computer, since there was no automatic identification request, I de-abilitate the cable connection. But this time I didn't find any way to rehabilitate it!

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

My "Wired AutoConfiguration" has the startup type "Automatic", but it's not enough to restart automatically the cable connection! I tried to do some standard things like restart the computer, unplug and plug in again the cable, reinstall the web-connection from the scratch... But nothing worked!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: by de-abilitate and rehabilitate, do you mean disconnect and reconnect?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I mean the following. I open the "Network and Sharing center", then I right click on  "Lan-connection" and pick the option de-abilitate. After that with WIndows XP I could find again the icon "Lan-connection" on "Network and Sharing center" and right-clicking on it there was the option "rehabilitate". With Windows 7 the icon "Lan-connection" is simply disappeared by "Network and Sharing center" (after the de-abilitation). I hope now I'm clear enough! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt and type `ipconfig /release` and than type `ipconfig /renew`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try as you suggest! If it works I'll accept your answer! (Unfortunately I cannot try now because I'm clearly connecting by another machine...)

Comment: Unfortunately it does seem that the commands you suggested are relative only to the wireless connections. Which is not my case! Anyhow thank you again for the try!